# Maintaining Referential Integrity Without Actually Deleting A Record

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

Rather than deleting an entry from the database, I am planning on using a boolean column like `isActive` in every table and manage its `true/false` state.

Normally when you delete a record from the database,

1. referential integrity is maintained, which means you cannot delete it if before deleting its dependencies.
2. when you query a deleted record, it returns null

How can I achieve the same results in an automated way using Entity Framework? Because checking isActive field for every entity in every query manually seems too much work which will be error-prone. And the same holds true for marking the dependencies as `isActive=false`.

**EDIT:**

My purpose is not limited to point-in-time queries. Let me give an example. UserA posted a photo and UserB wrote a comment on it. Then UserB wanted to delete his account. But the comment has its poster FK pointing at UserB. So, rather than deleting UserB, I want to deactivate its account but keep the record in order not to break dependencies.
And I want to extend this logic to every table in the database. Is that wrong?

Comment: So you want to avoid a null check to instead check a property of the record to see if it is active, which is what the null check satisfies, because you don't like referential integrity?

Comment: If you are planning on using a Boolean column, then you should plan on checking it.

Comment: @DarkBobG No, I don't want to phisically delete the records from the database, just mark them deleted. But at the same time enforce some kind of referential integrity with regard to this deletion status. It has to be done in the application, but I wonder if there can be an automated solution.

Comment: @WEI_DBA I was wondering if it makes sense to somehow change or extend the .where extension method to incorporate some kind of an automated solution.

Comment: There is no "tombstone" concept in SQL Server or any major RDBMS AFAIK. Adds cost to queries and probably needs some kinda index so more admin overhead. I don't know your business requirement for not physically deleting the data but if it is to allow point-in-time queries on the state of things at some time in the past, check out temporal tables in SQL Server 2016. Use that with Stretch database and you can keep history forever (or thereabouts).

Comment: @SQLmojoe My purpose is not limited to point-in-time queries. Let me give an example. UserA posted a photo and UserB wrote a comment on it. Then UserB wanted to delete his account. But the comment has its poster FK pointing at UserB. So, rather than deleting UserB, I want to deactivate its account but keep the record in order not to break dependencies.

Comment: Gotcha. In that case, you might want to consider a status column instead of a 1/0 isactive check. The scenario you described very often ends up with more than 2 possible states for a row (e.g. active, inactive, suspended, archive, delete). Remember that some countries require you to delete all data when a user leaves. A column with state info (e.g. tiny int) and another reference table with descriptions of each state is a common pattern. You can then create the appropriate views over the table for the common use cases as suggested by Michael.

Answer (score 1):

As kind of a side answer to this question, instead of querying all of the tables directly why not use Views and then query the views? You can place a filter in the view to only display the "IsActive = true" records, that way you don't have to worry about including it manually in every query (something you mention is error prone).

Answer (score 0):

> Because checking isActive field for every entity in every query manually seems too much work which will be error-prone

It is error prone. But you may not always want only the active records (admin page?). You may also not want to soft delete ALL records, as not everything makes sense to keep around (in my experience). You could use an Expression to help you out / wire it up for certain methods / repositories and build dynamic queries.

```
Expression<Func<MyModel, bool>> IsActive = x => x.IsActive;
```

> And the same holds true for marking the dependencies as isActive=false

A base repository could handle the delete for all your repositories, which would set the status to false (where the BaseModel would have an IsActive property).

```
        public int Delete<TEntity>(long id) where TEntity : BaseModel
        {
           using (var context = GetContext())
           {
              var dbEntity = context.Set<TEntity>().Find(id);
              dbEntity.IsActive = false;
              return context.SaveChanges();
           }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an OSS tool called EF Filters that can achieve what you are looking for: https://github.com/jbogard/EntityFramework.Filters

It let's you set global filters like an IsActive field and would certainly work for queries.